# How to solve $x^x = N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I was wondering whether there is a formula for solving $x^x = N$ for $x$. I thought I could just take logs, but the problem is that there are still two $x$'s and I need to express everything for one $x$ in terms of $N$.

Thanks.

Comment: Some functions will admit nice solutions, like a quadratic such as $x^2+2x+1=0$ or an exponential like $3^x = 9$.  When you start mixing exponentials and polynomials or start mixing other types of functions, things can quickly get very messy.  The solutions might no longer be "[elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) functions" and instead be "non-elementary."  Some non-elementary functions appear commonly enough that they are given their own name, but to a lay-person they are no better than saying the solution to the problem is "the solution" without any more info.

Comment: Your specific examples have nice solutions, but in general, equations like $x^2 + bx + c = 0$ and $a^x = b$ don't have any nicer solution than $x^x = a$. Using square roots and logarithms to solve your equations is no different from using the Lambert W function to solve the OP's equation.